# Shortcut to switch profile on CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, profiles

On my Android, I was looking for configuring profiles and under Settings found that I can configure profiles and there are some pre-existing ones like Home, Work, Silent, etc, with further settings to customize each of them. I'm assuming that this is a feature of my CyanogenMod installation and not part of Android itself.

Now, my question is what is the easiest way to switch profiles (say switch from 'Home' to 'Work'). I tried to find an option in the notification bar widget buttons in the CyanogenMod settings but couldn't find. Is there something that I can do that is quicker than going to Settings > Profiles > Select profile, may be a widget or something that works with the above mentioned CyanogenMod profiles and preferably not a new application with new profiles.

PS: I can see an option to 'Toggle Sound' but that's for switching Sound/Vibrate/Silent modes, whereas I need to switch profile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Holding the power button brings up the "power options" menu. In there you can choose the profile.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: wow! can't believe I missed that! Thanks @Ryan!

Answer (score 1):

There is now (confirmed with 10.2) a Profiles tile in the Quick Settings panel, which is quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

I had basically the same question. I noticed the option via the powers button, but wanted to have some kind of shortcut on the homescreen.

I found a solution using the app [CyanogenMod Profiles Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mufri.cmprofiles). Works for me on version 6.